# Converting mySQL select to SQL select

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have this mySQL select statement that works just as I need it to;

```
SELECT `requires`, `level` FROM `fp` WHERE `model` = '".$model."' GROUP BY `level` ORDER BY `menu_order`
```

In the table both *requires* and *level* are char fields. When sorted by *menu_order* the first row of each value of *level* will always be the value of *requires* that I want to retrieve.

For the SQL version I use;

```
SELECT requires, level FROM fp WHERE model = '" & model & "' GROUP BY level ORDER BY menu_order
```

Now when I try to run this same query on SQL I get;

requires'_is_invalid_in_the_select_list_because_it_is_not_contained_in_either_an_aggregate_function_or_the_GROUP_BY_clause

I found many examples of this error but all seem to be way more complicated than what I'm trying to do. Maybe I've been using mySQL for so long that my brain is stuck in that way of thinking.

How should that select statement be written in SQL?

Comment: You desperately need to apply some proper [SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/) here.

Comment: what is sql? SQL Server or PostgreSQL?

Comment: ANSI SQL... should be. I'm afraid MSSQL.

Comment: You would need to add Requires to your GROUP BY clause

Comment: MSSQL doesn't use `&` for concatenation

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be using a RDBMS that supports windowing functions (MS SQL Server, Postgres, Oracle), you can use `ROW_NUMBER` to number the rows for each value of `level`. Then you can pick out just the first one according to your order.

```
SELECT requires, level
FROM (
    SELECT requires, level, 
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY level ORDER BY menu_order) rn
    FROM fp
    WHERE model = '"' + model + '"'
) A
WHERE rn = 1
```

This is the correct translation of your query and satisfies your requirement:

> When sorted by *menu_order* the first row of each value of level will always be the value of requires that I want to retrieve.

Comment: I interpret the question as saying the author is trying to translate the query from mysql

Comment: The question was "how to convert from mySql to MSSQL"

Comment: Let me try your answer Chad. I think I can kind of understand what this is doing. BTW it's MS SQL on a Windows web server, if that helps.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Now I'll use your query to get a better understanding of SQL. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to convert your sql to MsSQL (if that's what you mean by SQL) exactly as there is a slight difference on how MySQL and MsSQL allow GROUP BY to be used.

Aggregates are function like SUM(), AVG(), COUNT(). Because requires is not an aggregate, it has to be in the list of GROUP BY, otherwise you get that error

You need to let us know what you are trying to do: I guess trying to find hierarchies?

MsSQL

```
SELECT level, requires 
FROM fp 
WHERE model = '" + model + "' 
GROUP BY level, requires
```

OR

```
SELECT level, count(*)
FROM fp 
WHERE model = '" + model + "' 
GROUP BY level
```

Comment: This is true, but it doesn't address the author's question: "When sorted by *menu_order* the first row of each value of level will always be the value of requires that I want to retrieve." My answer has a query that does just that.